# Navigation Drawer header cuttoff by action bar

Tags: android-layout

Navigation Drawer header cuttoff by action bar.But I need navigation drawer over action bar.[My Navigation drawer show in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvbHf.png)

My  style .xml

```
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay</item>
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sapphire_blue_light</item>
    <item name="background">@color/sapphire_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

And Drawer layout i add this line alsio

```
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

But i need result like below image.
[Result image i need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCe99.png)

My drawer layout.
My customized navigation drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_help"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:visibility="gone"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/grey"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >

      <include layout="@layout/nav_header" />
<ListView

    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/listview_side_view"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@color/listview_side_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: show your layout

Comment: add my drawer layout

Comment: you are having 3 children in your `drawerlayout` but it should contains only 2 children [please check the doc](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer)

Comment: i changed into 2 child  view i having same problem.Remove CoordinatorLayout . could suggest any

Comment: you can take a look at this [project](https://github.com/Kaushik1502/AndroidTabLayout)

Comment: In style theme "parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"" . But I need action bar theme . Bcz whole project i used  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Comment: you can use toolbar as actionbar and it is there

Comment: drawer layout overide on status  bar  but not hide action bar

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with theme **MyActionBar** :-

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sapphire_blue_light</item>
    <item name="background">@color/sapphire_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

Try after removing:-

```
<item name="background">@color/sapphire_blue_light</item>
```

If this not work try removing:-

```
<item name="android:background">@color/sapphire_blue_light</item>
```